# LSOF Command not showing java and class files

Tags: java, jar, terminal, command-prompt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I write the java file using BufferWriter to open and write the new file. But I didn't close the BufferWriter. Using lsof command to check how many files open in terminal. But the file is not showing in the list. Instead of using BufferWriter in jar, then I run the lsof command in terminal, Its shows that jar file. How to show the java or class file which contains the BufferWriter is not properly closed in terminal using lsof command.

For example in terminal,

```
      lsof +D /home/manoj/MyProject/WEB-INF
```

Thanks in Advance.. I am afraid that, I am not well in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as soon as your java process is closed, the file is also closed by the JVM. Also, you can not see which class opened the file, because lsof only lists processes, which is in any case a jvm process running your java code.

If you run java -jar, the jvm might keep the jar file opened, but if you run java on the classes, they are loaded into memory and then closed, so you cannot see which class files are opened by the JVM either.

Comment: please clarify what exactly you are trying to do. Do you just want to find parts in your code, where you forgot to close a BufferWriter or what?

Comment: Exactly right. But I don't want to generate my class files into jar. Instead of, find the non closing BufferWriter, FileOutPutStream in class file.

Comment: Well, just juse an IDE like NetBeans, search your source-code for "new FileOutputStream(" and check if you properly closed it. I don't think that any JVM keeps the class files open during runtime.